Oracle SQL : removing duplicates from output



FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH
SIXTH
SEVENTH




A
C
E
250
F
G
H


B
D
E
250
F
G
H


B
D
E
250
F
G
H


A
C
E
250
F
G
H


AB
QC
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP


CD
WD
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP


CD
WD
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP


AB
QC
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP



I have a table that contains 300k+ rows that has some parts like the above. I am not a DBM and I can only SELECT.
I am trying to remove duplicate rows from the query outputs but I do not know how to do it.
Desired output:



FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH
SIXTH
SEVENTH




A
C
E
250
F
G
H


B
D
E
250
F
G
H


AB
QC
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP


CD
WD
GG
1000
TT
SS
PP



Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t0 where t0 is your current table.


DELETE FROM your_table 
WHERE rowid not in (SELECT MIN(rowid) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);


Where column1, column2, and column3 make up the identifying key for each record. You might list all your columns.
